# What is JavaScript object without outer curly brackets?

Tags: javascript

I have noticed a thing I don't understand in JavaScript:

```
console.log(typeof msgObj)
console.log(msgObj)
```

prints:

```
object
something { something1: { something2: { something3: [Object] } } }
```

I would expect object to have outer curly brackets. Also when I try:

```
console.log(Object.keys(msgObj)[0])
```

I get

```
something1
```

What is "something" in this case?

Comment: Which browser? ...

Comment: What is msgobj here?

Comment: If you log an object to the console, the console is pretty free to display that in any way it wants/any way that makes it most usable to you.

Comment: I am using Node.js. msgObj is object created using protobufjs library

Comment: What is this "something" prefix then?

Comment: The class of the object.

Comment: I thought there are no classes in Js?

Comment: To-may-to, to-mah-to… ES6 *has* the `class` keyword, but that's still syntactic sugar over prototypes, which in the end mostly act like classes in practice anyway…

Comment: @user2449761 yes, kind of. But there is inheritance. And through that you can get a reference to the function that was called to construct the object. `(new Object).constructor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console tries to help you to find out where a certain object originated from, e.g.

```
 console.log(new User());
```

would log `User { ... }`. So the name before the brackets basically points you to the constructor of the object.